# What Protocol does Oracle client use when connecting PowerBI to oracle database?

Tags: oracle, odbc, powerbi

I have installed the Oracle client on my server & configured the TNS as per the database hosters instructions.
Powerbi can now connect to the Oracle datasource.

Id like clarity regarding what method PowerBI is connecting to the oracle source.
For example, I can connect to oracle via ODBC without using the Oracle Client.

Id like to know what protocol the oracle client is using and what are the benefits of using it over ODBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Power BI recommends installing the ODAC runtime for your environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-oracle-database). There is no alternative option. You might be asking why Power BI uses the Oracle ODP drivers instead of the Oracle ODBC driver - I'm pretty sure the answer is that [it's faster and supports more Oracle features](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/odp-096017.html), since it doesn't have to implement a bridge.

If you're frustrated with the large size of the Oracle Client or full ODAC developer downloads, you might be able to just install the ODAC XCopy runtimes, which are much smaller. ([32-bit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html), [64-bit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html))

---

To answer your question about protocols, as far as I know, *every* client uses the [Oracle Net](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/net_arch.htm#NETAG1511) component of the proprietary [Oracle Net Services](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/index-098579.html) network stack to connect the client to the server.

Then the client sends commands over the network connection. Again, as far as I know, most clients use the low-level [OCI library](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/oci.html) to do this.

There are a lot of different clients built on top of OCI:

- SQL*Plus
- SQL*Loader
- Datapump
- Oracle Instant Client
- Oracle Client (ie, "Thick Client")
- Oracle JDBC OCI driver
- Oracle ODBC driver, and [other drivers for Microsoft products](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html) (ODP.NET unmanaged, ASP.NET, OLE DB)

There's a few exceptions:

- Oracle JDBC Thin driver (entirely Java code)
- Oracle ODP managed driver (entirely .NET code)

There is also a [Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle), although Microsoft explicitly says to use the Oracle driver instead. It doesn't support most modern Oracle data features ("Unicode data types, BLOBs, CLOBs, and so on").

Comment: very helpful, thank you! I was asking as i was getting "ORA-03113 end-of-file on communication channel process ID:12345 Session ID:12 Serial number:12345" intermittently when refreshing my powerBI data. happens about 50% of the time. If i set up ODBC i dont get the error at all, so although slower, its reliable. Appreciate the info you have provided.